# dynamically allocating an array for a matrix

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-allocation

So i'm trying to allocat an array to hold a matrix of floats. the values passed in are ints (rows and cols) and the function is a pointer. so this is my function definition:

```
float *matrix(int rows,int cols)
{
    int i=0;
    float *m=NULL;
    m=(float *)malloc(rows*sizeof(int));
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        m[i]=(float*)malloc(cols*sizeof(int));
    }   
}
```

i have a feeling that this is wrong. i also get an error when i try to run. 
where exactly is the problem here? should the int be a float instead?

edit****

```
float *matrix(int rows,int cols)
{
    int i=0;
    float **m=NULL;
    m=(float *)malloc(rows*sizeof(float));
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        m[i]=(float *)malloc(cols*sizeof(float));
    }
}
```

alright if malloc doesn't run properly and fails i wan't to return NULL.
so it should be this code here, right?

```
if(m[i]==NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: A `float*` isn't an array of `float*`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int i=0;
    float **m; // You are looking for a pointer to pointer to float
    m=malloc(rows*sizeof(float*)); //Step1
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        m[i]=malloc(cols*sizeof(float)); //Step2
    }
```

---

**Notes**

1. You need not the cast the output of malloc for the reason mentioned in [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1620779) answer.
2. In step1, you allocate memory for **rows** `float*`s
3. For each of the `float*` in step1, we allocate memory to store **cols** `float`s in step2